# Segmentation fault in LinkedList destructor

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr->getNext() != nullptr) {
        Node *hold = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
        delete hold;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault at the while loop's condition when instantiating an empty LinkedList object. I'll add the Node and LinkedList class cpp files below as well.

## LinkedList.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
}

/** Make sure to dereference Node pointer when returning **/
Node* LinkedList::getNode(int e) {
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr->getNext()) {
        if (ptr->getExponent() == e) {
            return ptr;
        }
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void LinkedList::addNode(int c, string b, int e) {
    Node *n = nullptr;
    *n = Node(c, b, e);
    if (!head) {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    else if (n->getExponent() < n->getExponent()) {
        n->setNext(head);
        head = n;
    }
    else {
        Node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->getNext()) {
            if (ptr->getNext()->getExponent() > n->getExponent()) {
                n->setNext(ptr->getNext());
                ptr->setNext(n);
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr->getNext();
        }
        ptr->setNext(n);
    }
}

void LinkedList::deleteNode(int e) {
    if (!head) {
        return;
    }
    else if (head->getExponent() == e) {
        Node *hold = head;
        head = head->getNext();
        delete hold;
    }
    else {
        Node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->getNext()) {
            if (ptr->getNext()->getExponent() == e) {
                Node *hold = ptr->getNext();
                ptr->setNext(ptr->getNext()->getNext());
                delete hold;
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr->getNext();
        }
    }
}

string LinkedList::toString() {
    string line = "";
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr->getNext()) {
        line += ptr->getTerm() + "";
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    return line;
}

void LinkedList::derive() {

}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *ptr = head;
    while (ptr->getNext() != nullptr) {
        Node *hold = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
        delete hold;
    }
}
```

## Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
    coefficient = 0;
    base = "";
    exponent = 0;
    next = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(int c, string b, int e) {
    coefficient = c;
    base = b;
    exponent = e;
    next = nullptr;
}

string Node::getTerm() {
    stringstream term;
    term << coefficient << base << "^" << exponent;
    return term.str();;
}

Node::~Node() {}
```

Comment: What happens if `head` is a `nullptr` in your destructor? You will try to dereference it in the `while` loop and, doh, segmentation fault.

Comment: "..when instantiating an empty LinkedList object..", there is no check for `head != nullptr` so you have a dereference of an null pointer if the list is empty.

Comment: @crayzeewulf Segmentation fault, when I instantiate an empty LinkedList head is set to nullptr, it's in the default constructor.

Comment: @JacobGreenway, you are not handling this case correctly in the destructor as @Jack explained. If `head` is `nullptr` in the destructor, `ptr` will also be a `nullptr`. Hence, `ptr->getNext()` is going to dereference a null pointer. This is the cause of the segmentation fault you are getting.

Comment: @crayzeewulf Ok, that makes sense, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @JacobGreenway Fixing what? (I know s/he just said it, but I want to make sure you understand it, because you don't seem to)

Comment: @crayzweewulf Making it so that I don't dereference ptr->getNext() when head is a nullptr.  I'll try wrapping the while in and if(head != nullptr)

Comment: @crayzweewulf Ok, so I fixed the destructor, but now *n= Node(c, b, e); in the addNode function is giving me a seg fault.

Comment: *n= Node(c, b, e); should be n = new Node(c,b,e); Your code says "copy this Node to where n points". You mean "make a new Node and put a pointer to it in n"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I know that's not exactly the way you did it, and i might give you a wrong advice, but, if you put :

```
~Node() { delete getNext(); }
~LinkedList () { delete head; }
```

Then a function to pick up a specific node from the list and give the previous one the reference to the next, then you won't have to do all that complicated stuff, such as dereferencing nullptr.

/!\ In this case of course, you have to set the node you want to delete :

```
node_you_want_to_remove->next=nullptr;
```

(Read the comments below for further explanations)

Well, that's just my opinion, and if i'm wrong, i'd be glad to be explained why.

Have a good day.

Comment: 2 Problems. 1) Your answer doesn't check for `nullptr`. 2) What if you want some specific node (from a middle of the list) removed? You would end up deleting that node + everything that comes after it (which can be resolved by clever `nullptr` setting in delete logic, and, again, checking for it in the destructor).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `delete` already checks for null pointers.

Comment: @EJP Huh.. Never knew that. Probably because I am obsessed about trying not to access unallocated space (including not calling delete on null pointers). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `Node temp* = node_5.getNext();     node_5.setNext = temp->getNext();     temp->setNext = nullptr;      delete temp;` And then, you removed node_6 from your list without destroying everything. wether you do it from class Node or from class LinkedList.

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume Yes, that's what I mean by saying that you need to set pointers to `nullptr` in the delete code. And, as I said, I didn't know that you can delete `nullptr` without the code crashing.